# Are pthread synchronization primitives (locks/barrier) safe to use on SPARC when running under RMO?

Tags: pthreads, solaris, sparc

I plan to run some pthread-based parallel applications on a SPARC architecture, under the RMO memory model. I was just wondering if the pthread implementation is safe to use for such memory model, or I need to have a custom locking library?

thanks,

E.

Comment: What machine /OS are you targeting ? Cos I'm pretty sure that the UltrasparcII was the last to support RMO, and that's pretty old stuff now.

Answer (score 2):

This is an in-depth discussion of your question.

http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/atomic_sparc/

Short answer:

pthreads == ok.